# Removed golang but go command still works?

Tags: macos, go, terminal

I'm running Mac OSX Yosemite.

I'm trying update from golang 1.4 to golang 1.6. I uninstalled golang but I noticed I could still run the go command `go version =  go1.4.2 darwin/amd64`. Why is this so?

The directions aren't super clear IMO. They say

1. To remove an existing Go installation This is usually /usr/local/go
   (done) Remove etc/paths.d/go
2. I edited the bash by running `go version go1.4.2 darwin/amd64`

Comment: please, run command `which go`. It will print location of `go` binary

Comment: It prints ```usr/local/bin/go``` but when I go to ```usr/local/bin/``` there is no go directory. So how is the ```go``` command still running?

Comment: I guess i had to look at it through terminal

Comment: I can only recommend you use [GVM](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm) to help you avoid these problems in the future.

Comment: Maybe you still have binary in `/usr/local/bin` directory named `go`?

Comment: when you run 'which xxx' it tells you where the executable xxx lives, so if it said /usr/local/bin/go, it means (as @s7anley said) you have the binary go in /usr/local/bin.   Did you install it via homebrew (which puts stuff there by default)?  if so, homebrew will upgrade it next time you to an update / upgrade

Answer (score 5):

I was running into the same issue. I ended up with this solution:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
rm go
```

**Removes the 'go' command**

Then go back to golang.org and re-download the newest version, run the installer and when you run the 'go' command it will display 1.12.9 (As of writing this post).

Answer (score 4):

**You can try this**

```
sudo apt-get remove golang-go
```

**Then do this**

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove golang-go
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran `source ~/.bash_profile` and that updated the env variables.