# How to uninstall Go?

Tags: go

I tried the answer here [Removed golang but go command still works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643576/removed-golang-but-go-command-still-works), but it didn't work (I can still run go)

Currently, when I run `which go` I see this output

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

I think I had two installations of go as my `GOPATH` was pointing to another folder named `gocode`. I've now removed that folder, and the `usr/local/go/bin/go` folder.

I've also removed my `GOPATH`. However, I can still run `go`.

How do I uninstall go?

Comment: How did you install it? If you installed it with a package manager, remove it with it. Otherwise just delete the files (wherever they installed to) and remove any environment variables.

Comment: Perhaps you want `rm -rvf /usr/local/go/`, but be careful before trying that. Also remove any mention of `go` in e.g. your `~/.bashrc` then logout and login again.

Comment: Unfortunately...I don't remember (I did this a while back)

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson that's what I've done.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that worked - want to provide an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @praks5432: I did add an answer

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You might try

```
rm -rvf /usr/local/go/
```

then remove any mention of `go` in e.g. your `~/.bashrc`; then you need at least to logout and login.

However, be careful when doing that. You might break your system badly if something is wrong.

<sup>PS. I am assuming a Linux or POSIX system.</sup>

Comment: I also recommend using https://github.com/moovweb/gvm it's made everything clean.

Comment: When installed via OsX graph.installer, remove also :  sudo rm /etc/paths.d/go. (this removes old go-binary from PATH).

Comment: Don't forget `sudo ...` unless you're someone that likes to run everything as root...

Comment: thanks, Basile it worked for me, but need to add "**sudo rm -rvf /usr/local/go/**" otherwise we get permission denial in mac os calalina

Comment: this doesn't work if in case you installed multiple go versions. 
so it's always better to run this sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove golang-go

Comment: praks5432's comment above - using gvm - should be an answer, that's a fantastic tool and just saved me quite a bit of headache

Comment: use @praks5432's suggested `gvm`. It actually takes away a lot of the headache.

Answer (score 239):

**Update August 2019**

Found the [official uninstall docs](https://golang.org/doc/manage-install#uninstalling) worked as expected (on Mac OSX).

```
$ which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

In summary, to uninstall:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go
$ sudo rm /etc/paths.d/go
```

Then, did a fresh install with homebrew using `brew install go`. Now, i have:

```
 $ which go
/usr/local/bin/go
```

Comment: if you downvote, please can you leave a comment to clarify your reason. The above answer references and agrees with the official docs (Mac OSX). What didn't work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately that link doesn't go to uninstall docs anymore.

Comment: I didnt DV but this would only work if you've installed to those paths which is only the Go packed install wizard thing. Installs via scripts, automation or choice can be anywhere.

Comment: Is there any advantage to use homebrew for installing Go, rather than the official *.pkg installer?

Comment: @tom I have fixed the link to official docs

Comment: re: "*Is there any advantage to use homebrew for installing Go, rather than the official *.pkg installer?*" As with any package managers, using Homebrew just makes it convenient to update/upgrade and uninstall. No need to manually do these `rm` commands to uninstall Go.

Comment: also you have to delete gofmt

Answer (score 84):

I'm using Ubuntu. I spent a whole morning fixing this, tried all different solutions, when I type go version, it's still there, really annoying...
Finally this worked for me, hope this will help!

```
sudo apt-get remove golang-go
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove golang-go
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm on a mac and I had to use `brew uninstall go` to uninstall with homebrew - your answer set me on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for this, Worked on my Kali Linux

Comment: I used the these 2 commands  `sudo apt remove golang-go` & `sudo apt remove --auto-remove golang-1.13`

Answer (score 18):

**On a Mac-OS system**

1. If you have used an installer, you can uninstall golang by using the same installer.
2. If you have installed from source

   ```
   rm -rf /usr/local/go
   rm -rf $(echo $GOPATH)
   ```

Then, remove all entries related to go i.e. GOROOT, GOPATH from `~/.bash_profile` and run

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

**On a Linux system**

```
rm -rf /usr/local/go
rm -rf $(echo $GOPATH)
```

Then, remove all entries related to go i.e. GOROOT, GOPATH from `~/.bashrc` and run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: "*you can uninstall golang by using the same installer.*" No you can't. Re-running the same installer will just do a fresh re-installation. There was no "uninstall" option.

Answer (score 18):

### Update (Sep, 2022)

[The official page](https://go.dev/doc/manage-install) has changed path for the uninstallation help along with the help text. Here is what it says now.

> #### Uninstalling Go
>
> You can remove Go from your system using the steps
> described in this topic.
>
> ##### Linux / macOS / FreeBSD
>
> 1. Delete the go directory.
>    This is usually
>    /usr/local/go.
> 2. Remove the Go bin directory from your PATH environment variable.
>    Under Linux and FreeBSD, edit /etc/profile or $HOME/.profile. If you
>    installed Go with the macOS package, remove the /etc/paths.d/go file.
>
> ##### Windows
>
> The simplest way to remove Go is via Add/Remove Programs in
> the Windows control panel:
>
> 1. In Control Panel, double-click Add/Remove Programs.
> 2. In Add/Remove
>    Programs, select Go Programming Language, click Uninstall, then follow
>    the prompts.
>
> For removing Go with tools, you can also use the command
> line:
>
> - Uninstall using the command line by running the following command:
>   `msiexec /x go{{version}}.windows-{{cpu-arch}}.msi /q`
>   **Note:** Using this
>   uninstall process for Windows will automatically remove Windows
>   environment variables created by the original installation.

### Original Answer

From the [official install page](https://golang.org/doc/install) -

> To remove an existing Go installation from your system delete the go
> directory. This is usually `/usr/local/go` under Linux, macOS, and
> FreeBSD or `c:\Go` under Windows.
>
> You should also remove the Go `bin` directory from your PATH environment
> variable. Under Linux and FreeBSD you should edit `/etc/profile` or
> `$HOME/.profile`. If you installed Go with the [macOS package](https://golang.org/doc/install#macos) then you
> should remove the `/etc/paths.d/go` file. Windows users should read the
> section about [setting environment variables under Windows](https://golang.org/doc/install#windows_env).

Comment: @zixuan The quoted text explains it very well. Nobody mentioned the official docs, so I did. Do you find it ambiguous?

Answer (score 12):

For Windows 10:

1. Go to `Apps` in the `Settings` App.
2. Look for `Go Programming Language *` in the list and uninstall it.
3. Remove `C:\Go\bin` from your `PATH` environment variable (only if you don't plan on installing another version of golang)

Answer (score 7):

Use this command to uninstall Golang for Ubuntu.

This will remove just the golang-go package itself.

```
sudo apt-get remove golang-go
```

Uninstall golang-go and its dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove golang-go
```

Comment: @adrian W can you please explain what is my mistakes.

Comment: Nobody said it is a mistake. Just reformatted to suit the style which is usual in SO posts. I.e. text which is literal computer in/output (such as a shell command) is formatted as code block. It was formatted as citation before.

Answer (score 4):

I just have to answer here after reading such super-basic advice in the other answers.

For MacOS the default paths are:

1. /user/bracicot/go (working dir)
2. /usr/local/go (install dir)

When uninstalling remove both directories.
If you've installed manually obviously these directories may be in other places.

One script I came across installed to `/usr/local/.go/` a hidden folder because of permissioning... this could trip you up.

In terminal check:

```
echo $GOPATH
echo $GOROOT
#and
go version
```

For me after deleting all go folders I was still getting a go version.

Digging through my system path `echo $PATH`

`/Users/bracicot/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:`

revealed some places to check for still-existing go files such as `/usr/local/bin`

> Another user mentioned: `/etc/paths.d/go`

You may also want to remove `GOPATH` and `GOROOT` environment variables.
Check .zshsrc and or .bash_profile.
Or you can `unset GOPATH` and `unset GOROOT`

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall `go` on MacOS, do this:
On the terminal type `which go` it will; return a path like this `/usr/local/go/bin/go`
Go to the root folder of `go` which is `/usr/local/go/` and type on the terminal `rm -rf /usr/local/go/` . you may get permission denied depending on your system setup, so the command should be prefixed with sudo like this

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go/
```

It will request for your password, just enter it.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get remove golang-go
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove golang-go
```

This is perfect for Ubuntu 18.18

Comment: Ubuntu 18.18? Ubuntu versions can only have 4, 6 or 10 as their suffixes.

Answer (score 1):

**On a Mac-OS Catalina**

1. need to add sudo before rm -rf /usr/local/go **sudo rm -rf /usr/local/go**
   otherwise, we will run into permission denial.
2. **sudo vim ~/.profile** or **sudo ~/.bash_profile** remove **export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/BIN** or anything related to 
   go lang
3. If you use Zsh shell, then you need to remove the above line to ~/.zshrc file.

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

In MacOS, you can just do it with `brew`:

```
brew uninstall go
brew install go
brew upgrade go
```

Comment: op asks how to **un**install

Comment: What makes you think that the OP used Brew to install Go?

Answer (score -1):

On linux we can do like this to remove go completely:

```
rm -rf "/usr/local/.go/"
rm -rf "/usr/local/go/"
```

These two command remove go and hidden .go files. Now we also have to update entries in shell profile.

Open your basic file. Mostly I open like this `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc` and remove all go mentions.

You can also do by sed command in ubuntu

```
sed -i '/# GoLang/d' .bashrc
sed -i '/export GOROOT/d' .bashrc
sed -i '/:$GOROOT/d' .bashrc
sed -i '/export GOPATH/d' .bashrc
sed -i '/:$GOPATH/d' .bashrc
```

It will remove Golang from everywhere. Also run this after running these command

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Tested on linux 18.04 also. That's All.

Answer (score -3):

1. Go to the directory

   ```
   cd /usr/local
   ```
2. Remove it with super user privileges

   ```
   sudo rm -rf go
   ```

Answer (score -3):

only tab
`rm -rvf /usr/local/go/`
not works well, but
`sudo rm -rvf /usr/local/go/`
do.

Comment: That's because anything cannot be used directly in Linux anywhere except for your `/home/your account/...` account folder that you *own*.

Comment: It's a common knowledge to remove something with sudo in Linux.