# Failed to compile Go file - "initialization failure...xxxx redeclared in this block"

Tags: go, compilation

I am new in Go and I follow the instructions in the [website](https://golang.org/doc/install) and the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7RILbHoLBA) I am getting the follow errors when I run `go build hello.go`:

```
go: disabling cache (/home/myuser/.cache/go-build) due to initialization failure: open /home/myuser/.cache/go-build/log.txt: permission denied
# runtime
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/map.go:64:2: bucketCntBits redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:64:18
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/map.go:65:2: bucketCnt redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:65:23
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/map.go:69:2: loadFactorNum redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:69:18
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/map.go:70:2: loadFactorDen redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:70:18
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/map.go:76:2: maxKeySize redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:76:17
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/map.go:77:2: maxValueSize redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:77:17
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/map.go:82:2: dataOffset redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:85:4
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/map.go:91:2: empty redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:91:19
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/map.go:92:2: evacuatedEmpty redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:92:19
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/map.go:93:2: evacuatedX redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/hashmap.go:93:19
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/map.go:93:2: too many errors
```

It wrote `permission denied` but I tried to run it with `sudo go build` and it also failed with:

> sudo: go: command not found

I am working on Ubuntu 16.4. 
My go file `hello.go` is in `$HOME/Desktop/go/src/hello`.

My file `$HOME/myuser/.profile` contains:
`PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin"`

Comment: `chown`/`chmod` the cache directory in your home path, but that's a separate thing that has nothing to do with the error. You must have made a mistake during the installation, here's a github thread where some people encountered the same issue as you: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-install Go fixed the issue.
The problem happened because I installed new version of Go on top a previous one.

**The solution:**
1. [Remove Go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42186042/2153777): `rm -rvf /usr/local/go/`
2. Install it again from [Golang website](https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.14.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz):

```
cd ~/go/Downloads
// Depends on the version you download
tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.14.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
cd ~/go/src/myproj/
go build
// no errors
```

Answer (score 2):

Gopath

```
The GOPATH environment variable lists places to look for Go code.
On Unix, the value is a colon-separated string. On Windows, the value 
is a semicolon-separated string. On Plan 9, the value is a list.

GOPATH must be set to get, build and install packages outside the standard Go tree.
Use tool like dep to segregate your different go project, maintaining your project dependencies.
```

Goroot

```
 The Go binary distributions assume they will be installed in /usr/local/go (or c:\Go under Windows), but it is possible to install 
the Go tools to a different location. In this case you must set the 
GOROOT environment variable to point to the directory in which it was installed.
```

so its always preferred to make your own gopath for compiling your code.
GOPATH is for your own go projects / 3rd party libraries (downloaded with "go get").

Comment: I didn't understand what is the solution? You just explained what is `GOPATH` and `GOROOT` but what is the solution that will help the user?