# vscode does not detect errors golang

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

My vscode does not detect errors in golang.

Example:

```
package somepackage

import "fmt"

func f(name string) string {
    name = 1
    return name
}
```

This should throw a type error, but it does not. I never get any errors.

My `settings.json` contains

```
"go.gopath": "some/path", 
"go.vetOnSave": "package",
"go.lintOnSave": "package",
"go.testOnSave": true,
"go.buildOnSave": "package",
"go.coverOnSave": true
```

I was able to run `go: install/update Tools`. All tools are installed successfully.

I am also able to run debug a .go file in vscode.

Comment: Is your GOROOT path set? Also are there any other go files in the same project where there might an error?

Comment: Yes, I inserted `go.goroot` in my application. Apparently, I have two conflicting go installations on my computer. After recompiling the tools, vscode was able to detect errors. Thanks! Please submit your suggestion as an answer so I can close this issue.

Comment: I keep seeing "go: install/update tools" in documentation. Has this option been removed recently? I'm assuming it was an old menu setting Go > Install/update tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @pwaterz pointed out, the solution to my problem was to add `"go.goroot: /some/other/path"`.

The reason that vscode was not able to detect errors was, that there are different go versions on my computer. Adding the goroot and running `go: install/update Tools` solved the problem.

**---- Edit: Multiple go versions ----**

Had multiple conflicting go versions on my Mac, pulled in via brew. Fixed the problem with a reinstall.

- [Uninstall go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186003/how-to-uninstall-golang) and also run `brew uninstall go`
- [Reinstall go](https://golang.org/doc/install)
- Set environment variables in your `.bash_profile` or similar. Compare [here](https://gist.github.com/vsouza/77e6b20520d07652ed7d).
- Apply the changes to your profile by running e.g. `source .bash_profile`
- Restart VSCode
- In `settings.json` set `"go.goroot": "/usr/local/go"`
- Run `go: Toggle workspace trust space` to make sure changes to `settings.json` are applied (you have to trust your workspace for that)
- `go: Install/update tools` and select all

**---- Edit: Incorrect root folder ----**

Make sure that you open the root folder of your project and not a sub-folder of your project. That may cause in invalid import paths otherwise

**---- Edit: Broken language server ----**

- Try to run `go: restart language server`
- You may see [Error loading workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66141927/vs-code-go-extension-fails-to-load-due-to-it-being-unable-to-change-go-mod)
- run `go mod tidy` and try again

Comment: I had this problem again. Be aware that you may need to `Go: Toggle Workspace Trust Flag` before running `go: install/update Tools`. Otherwise the change to `go.goroot` will be ignored.

Comment: Nice, running `Go: Install/Update tools` from the command palette worked for me.