# Fail to build with code Go: "redeclared in this block"

Tags: go, compilation

When I am trying to build (`go build hello.go`) the following code:

```
// ~/go/src/myproj/hello.go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
# runtime/internal/atomic
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:13:6: Load redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:16:24
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:19:6: Loadp redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:22:32
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:25:6: Load64 redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:28:26
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:31:6: LoadAcq redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:34:27
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:36:6: Xadd redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:39:37
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:39:6: Xadd64 redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:42:39
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:42:6: Xadduintptr redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:45:47
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:45:6: Xchg redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:48:36
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:48:6: Xchg64 redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:51:38
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:51:6: Xchguintptr redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64.go:54:45
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/atomic_amd64x.go:51:6: too many errors
```

**My Go settings:**
Go version: `go1.14.4 linux/amd64`
GOPATH: `/home/jiren/go`
GOROOT: `/usr/local/go`
PATH: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin`

Any idea what is the problem?

I hope someone can explain me how to solve this issue.
I know what is the meaning of `GOPATH` and `GOROOT` so no need to refer me to other solutions\docs.

Comment: You appear to have a corrupt go installation. Did you install a new version over another maybe? I'd clear and reinstall go.

Comment: Oh, maybe yes. I will try and update, thanks !

Comment: Yep it solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The suggestion of @Burak Serdar to re-install Go fixed the issue.
The problem happened because I installed new version of Go on top a previous one.

**The solution:**
1. [Remove Go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42186042/2153777): `rm -rvf /usr/local/go/`
2. Install it again from [Golang website](https://golang.org/doc/install?download=go1.14.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz):

```
cd ~/go/Downloads
// Depends on the version you download
tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.14.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
cd ~/go/src/myproj/
go build
// no errors
```

Comment: This post solved my issue and ChatGPT 4 doesn't quite diagnoze this one.